# Find an index n such that inequality is true

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation

I need to find an index $n$ such that: $|e^{x} - S_{n}(x)| \leq \frac{|e^{x}|}{10^{4}}$ (1),
where $S_{n} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \frac{x^{k}}{k!}$ is the n-th Partial Sum of $e^x$.

Let $x$ be a constant, for instance $x = 1$.

My approach was to rewrite the equation (1) in this manner: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1^{k}}{k!} = e \cdot (1-10^{-4}) \approx 2.718010000$ (2)

So in the end we need to find an index $n$ which approximates the first 4 Digits of $e^{x}$.

Now this can be easily solved with the help of a computer, for instance by programming.
However the algorithm I implemented would be a pain in the ass if someone has to manually calculate and find this particular $n$.

Is there any more efficient way than iterating through the Partial Sum $S_n$ and check when the difference between $e^{x}$ and the temporary result of the Partial Sum $S_n$ is less than the wanted approximation?

With kind regards,

optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bound the index $n$ using Taylor formula in Lagrange form $e^{x}-S_n(x)=x^{n+1}e^c/(n+1)!$, 
where $c$ is between $0$ and $x$. This implies that $0\le e^{x}-S_n(x)\le x^{n+1}e^x/(n+1)!$ if 
 $x\ge 0$ and $0\le e^{x}-S_n(x)\le x^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ if $x<0$.

Comment: Lagrange's form of the remainder is ${f^{(n+1)}(c)\over(n+1)!}\>x^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is positive, one asks that $\mathrm e^x|1-P[X\leqslant n]|\leqslant c\mathrm e^x$ where $X$ is Poisson with parameter $x$ and $c=10^{-4}$, or, equivalently, $P[X\gt n]|\leqslant c$.

Since $c$ is small, one is interested in large deviations of $X$ from its mean hence one can get approximate solutions using exponential estimates. For every $u\gt1$, the pointwise inequality $u^n\mathbf 1_{X\gt n}\leqslant u^X$ is almost sure hence 
$$
u^nP[X\gt n]\leqslant E[u^X]=\mathrm e^{x(u-1)}.
$$
For every fixed $n$, the upper bound $u^{-n}\mathrm e^{x(u-1)}$ is minimal when $u=n/x$, hence, assuming that $n\gt x$ because $n=tx$ with $t\gt1$,
$$
P[X\gt n]\leqslant x^nn^{-n}\mathrm e^{n-x}=u(t)^x,\quad u(t)=t^{-t}\mathrm e^{t-1}.
$$
Finally, every $n=tx$ where $t\gt1$ solves the question as soon as
$$
u(t)\leqslant c^{1/x}.
$$
If $x=1$ and $c=10^{-4}$, $u(7)\approx5\cdot10^{-4}$ and $u(8)\approx7\cdot10^{-5}$ hence one can choose $n=8$.

---

If $x=0$, one can choose every $n\geqslant0$. If $x\lt0$, the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ becomes alternated after the rank $|x|$ hence it differs from its limit at most by the absolute value of the last term. Thus, it suffices to choose $n=-tx$ with $t\geqslant1$ such that 
$$(-x)^{-tx}/(-tx)!\leqslant c\mathrm e^{x}.
$$
Since $n!\geqslant n^n/\mathrm e^n$, for every $x\lt0$, $n=-tx$ where $t\gt1$ solves the question as soon as
$$
t^{-t}\mathrm e^{1+t}\leqslant c^{-1/x}.
$$
If $t=9$, the LHS is about $5\cdot10^{-5}$ hence $n=9$ solves the case $x=-1$ and $c=10^{-4}$.